# magento 1.3 export data to 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I would like to export data (categories, products, orders, customers etc) from magento 1.3.2.4 to 1.7.0.2 version.

I tried exporting the CSV files from the 1.3 version but the associations etc are not loading properly

Is there a way for me to do it via the Database?

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Comment: The version difference is great, there are lots of change. The following link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes/13194474#13194474

Answer (score 1):

[Magento upgrade takes too long and never completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes/13194474#13194474) Please  check this url, might help you as i was successful while migrating 1.4 to 1.7